# Algorithm for Scheduling Independent Parallel Tasks

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Can you suggest me algorithms for  scheduling independent parallel tasks. Each task has runtime and frequency. Also there is a maximum count of tasks that can be executed parallely.

Comment: Have you looked into Quartz http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Yes, but I want optimized algorithm for scheduling tasks

Comment: Why do you think Quartz is not optimal? By the way, you may have to define your optimization benchmarks before designing an algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you might want with "algorithms" to do so, most of the actual algorithmic work is done at a very low level in the JVM via threading, which gets quite complicated the more you get into it (to the point where you're looking at what the actual physical processor is doing).

Something you might be interested in are the tools already provided Java core libraries for doing this:

You can use any desired number of [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)s that can each take on parts of the workload; you can also schedule batches of smaller tasks to run on a fixed number of threads with a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), which can be provided with any number of tasks that will then be executed whenever possible by a specific number of threads.

If you actually need to schedule / delay these tasks, you can also use some other variant of [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), such as a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), which can execute and even re-execute various commands at pre-determined delays with a limited pool of threads.

Unless you somehow have almost no access to base Java libraries, it is highly recommended that you use these or something similar as they will probably work with less effort, more reliably, and probably faster than reinventing the wheel yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quartz Schedular. It gives you the power to schedule N parallel jobs with each having independent start delay and repeat frequency. Also you can have a cron job for your tasks as well. You can deploy it using a war or a jar or from a simple java class' main function